How select the first tab in the top bar navigation in React Native when returning from another menu
import React, { Component,useEffect } from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { SafeAreaView,StackLayout,Button,TouchableOpacity,Image,Text, View ,StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import { useIsFocused,NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

 
 
 
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TopTabsGroup = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

 

function BeritaTerkini (){
return(
  <View>
    <Text> Berita Terkini </Text>
      </View>
)
}


function Terpopuler (){

  return(
    <View>
      <Text> Terpopuler </Text>
        </View>
  )
}

 



function TopTabroup(props){
 const { initialRouteName } = props;

    return (
      <TopTabsGroup.Navigator   initialRouteName={"Berita Terkini"} >
        <TopTabsGroup.Screen name='Berita Terkini'   component={BeritaTerkini}    /> 
        <TopTabsGroup.Screen name='Terpopuler' component={Terpopuler}/> 
 
     </TopTabsGroup.Navigator>
)
}


function TabGroup (){
    return(
      <Tab.Navigator       screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarActiveTintColor :'red',
        tabBarInactiveTintColor :'black',
      }} >
          <Tab.Screen name='Berita Terkini' component={TopTabroup}
           options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'BERITA TERKINI',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <Icon name="home" color={color} size={20} />
            ),
          }}
          /> 
          <Tab.Screen name='Topik' component={Topik}
           options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'TOPIK',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <Icon name="microphone" color={color} size={20} />
            ),
          }}/> 
       
  
    )
  }


export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    
    return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.Header}>
           <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/logo.png')} />
           
           </View>
            <TabGroup/>
            </View>
    )
  }
}

when I run the application and enter another page and return to the home page, the top tab navigation does not return to the first tab, but remains on the tab that was selected...I use react-native not expo
when I run the application and enter another page and return to the home page, the top tab navigation does not return to the first tab, but remains on the tab that was selected...I use react-native not expo

Ensure your app wraps it with NavigationContainer, where navigation will take place. For top tabs, use a Stack Navigator and name it TopTabStack. In the TabGroup, the function using the hook use navigation to do the navigation to the first screen of the TopTabs stack will be invoked and the screen will be named 'Berita Terkini' when a custom button, which is attached to the view of the TopTab stack, is clicked. Also, set the initialRouteName for 'TopTabs' to make it the first thing anyone sees when they launch the application.

One way to reset top tab selection is to listen tabPress and navigate to the first tab. Something like this:
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function TopTabs({ navigation }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('tabPress', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      navigation.navigate('Home');
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={...} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={...} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function BottomTabs() {
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen name="Tab1" component={TopTabs} />
      <BottomTab.Screen name="Tab2" component={...} />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}

